# File downloads black file

Tags: php, file, header, download

So $fmain is equal to the file path, the and the randomly generated file name, it then fwrites 100 lines of html literal text (Using the ' '). That's great and all, but it then saves to the server, which is fine, but then it downloads to the client (the one that requested the file download) and it's blank. Does anyone have any ideas? This is all on the same page by the way. The file is complete on the server itself, but not when it's downloaded to the client.

```
fwrite($file, $line98 );
fwrite($file, $numberNewline);
fwrite($file, $line99 );
fwrite($file, $numberNewline);
fwrite($file, $line100 );
fwrite($file, $numberNewline);



fclose($file);

if (file_exists($fmain)) {
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($fmain));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fmain));
ob_clean();
flush();
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is just sending the headers, you should `readfile` also before `ob_clean()`. For instance it could be:

```
if (file_exists($fmain)) {
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($fmain));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fmain));
readfile($fmain);
ob_clean();
flush();
exit;
}
```